# How to convert WinTree to TreeView in a CodedUI test?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, coded-ui-tests

I am testing a WinForms application with CodedUI tests.

A TreeView control was identified by my test as a WinTree control.

As far as I understand, the TreeView class provides SelectedNode method, which I need. So, I want to convert the WinTree object into a TreeView object. But I get the error, when I try to cast:

> Cannot convert type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls.WinTree' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView'

Here is my test code (amended a bit)

```
WinWindow myWinWindow = this.myWindow;
WinTree myWinTree = (WinTree)myWinWindow.GetChildren().Where(control => control.ControlType.ToString() == "Tree").First();

TreeView myTreeView = (TreeView)myWinTree;
```

Is there a way to get the TreeView object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The UI elements generated in the UIMap are derived from the WinControl class and I can't find a TreeView under its namespace so I don't think you can convert a WinTree to TreeView (one is a Windows form control the other is a UI Test control so casting is impossible here).

But I see that you are familiar with lambda expressions so you could use the same to get the selected node. Something like:

```
myWinTree.GetChildren().First(x => (bool)x.GetProperty(WinTreeItem.PropertyNames.Selected));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Kida. I will try your advice.